# Move baker to new physical server

Tags: baker

**Goal:**

I would like to move my baker to a new server infrastructure.

**Problem:**

What files do I have to copy from which directories and what steps do I have to complete?

**Attempt:**

1. Install new machine
2. Generate new identity
3. Import snapshot
4. Start and synchronize node until up-to-date
5. Stop processes on old machine
6. Copy and overwrite all files from folders ./tezos-node and ./tezos-client including node identity to new server
7. Start new server?

**Desired result:**

I still have my old identity, nonce file is preserved and my alias for my addresses are available. I am not sure about a lot of files which are additionally stored in the mentioned folders.

**Question:**

Can you please correct my steps and give feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two issues:

- You only want to copy and overwrite config.json, peers.json and version.json in .tezos-node as well as all settings in the .tezos-client config directory.
- Overwriting the blockchain data folders store,context within the .tezos-node directory would take a long time. Also if you plan to do that, syncing a new node with a new identity would not have any benefits.

Comment: The new identity would only be necessary if I would like to sync the node in parallel to still operating the old one, right?

Comment: Running multiple nodes with the same identitiy might not be a good idea, but it's not clear whether it's supported. This is a new question.